# Django 1.4 using Apache Virtual Host

Tags: django

I'm installing django 1.4 on Apache and I intended to use the same webserver for PHP apps too.
My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. If I do configurations on the main conf file, the localhost will point straight away to the Django installation page,even the PHP apps too.So I created a vhost file at /etc/apache2/sites-available and name it as 'project'. However, seems to me, it fails to point to the wsgi file.
This is my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/
    ServerName project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project/project/wsgi.py

    <Directory "/var/www/project/project">
         <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
         </Files>
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This is my wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/project')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

What am I missing? I strongly believe it's something to do with the `<VirtualHost>` directive
because it won't read the wsgi file even I intentionally do some syntax errors there and Apache doesn't detect these when I restart it.

Comment: Did you make a link from your `sites-available` file to `sites-enabled` to actually enable it?

Comment: After executing a2ensite project, symlinks will be automatically generated inside sites-enabled.

Comment: maybe other configuration is overwriting your settings? Disable all other config files in sites-enabled and see if it works.

Comment: Okay, now, after putting Include sites-enabled/project inside apache2.conf and restarting the webserver I got a 500 error,but this time it reads the wsgi file. The error from the log is:  ImportError: Could not import settings 'project.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named project.settings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's dumb. I almost forgot that python will run on port 8000!

I actually need to go into the first level of the project folder and run the Django development server by executing: `python manage.py runserver`

Thanks.